# Excel How can I first scan for a match then split part of the row and create a column on the end of the row?

Tags: excel, row

```
32P 32P 9/10/2019   9/13/2019                       
32P 32P 9/24/2019   9/27/2019                       
38G 38G 9/10/2019   9/13/2019                       
38G 38G 9/25/2019   9/30/2019                       
3D5 3D5 9/3/2019    9/6/2019                        
3D5 3D5 9/10/2019   9/13/2019
```

I want to consolidate this table so that there are no rows with the same 3 letter grouping, and create more columns on the end of the row to put the data.

Is there a VBA or formula that can make the result look like this on its own?

```
32P 32P 9/10/2019   9/13/2019   9/24/2019   9/27/2019                                           
38G 38G 9/10/2019   9/13/2019   9/25/2019   9/30/2019                                           
3D5 3D5 9/3/2019    9/6/2019    9/10/2019   9/13/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Work from the bottom up and delete the duplicate rows once you've moved the dates up.

Remember to sort the data first.

```
dim i as long
with sheet1
  for i=.cells(.rows.count, 1) to 2 step -1
    if .cells(i, 1)=.cells(i-1, 1) then
      .cells(i-1, 5).resize(1, 2) = .cells(i, 3).resize(1, 2)
      .cells(i, 3).entirerow.delete
    end if
  next i
end with
```